# EasyNetQ debug issue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

We have RabbitMQ working for us for some time now but recently we starting getting below error

> EasyNetQ.EasyNetQException: No handler found for message type

To look what happening, i download EasyNetQ from `Git` and now when i try to debug, i get below error in file AdvancedBusEventHandlers.cs of EasyNetQ shared project. Checking RabbitMQ page, the most stable version is get is 3.6.4 so dont know whats happening here.

[image: Error in file AdvancedBusEventHandlers.cs]

Have anyone come across this error? or anything anyone can recommend for this fix?

Thanks

Comment: Try "Restore NuGet Packages if the library is from NuGet or Try removing the reference to assembly and add reference again. I have seen this when you load your project from github or some repositories, you have to add reference to some libraries manually.

Comment: I upgraded the packages to 4.0.0.0 in the morning so something got struck somewhere. Thanks for the pointer @RahulMakwana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "Restore NuGet Packages if the library is from NuGet or Try removing the reference to assembly and add reference again. I have seen this when you load your project from github or some repositories, you have to add reference to some libraries manually.